# create HICON from memory on windows

Tags: c, winapi

I have the contents of a `.ico` file in memory as a `const char*`, and I wish to create a `HICON` from this data. My current approach is to write the data to a temporary file and then use `LoadImage`. Is it possible to instead create the icon directly from memory?

Comment: Yes. Parse the file and create the icon.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm trying to avoid creating a file. I have the contents of the icon in memory as a character array and wish to create a HICON directly from that data.

Comment: Have a look at `CreateIconFromResource`.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Icon.cs,e01910ea8cd8d6a8

Comment: So don't create a file. Parse the content and create the icon.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks - my question is about how to do exactly that.

Comment: There are plenty of articles on the ico format. Read them and take it from there.

Comment: If you can use [GDI+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798.aspx), you can wrap the raw ICO data in an `IStream` using `CreateStreamOnHGlobal()` or `SHCreateMemStream()`, and then pass that stream to the `Bitmap` class constructor or `Bitmap::FromStream()` method, and then finally call the `Bitmap::ToHICON()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this without using GDI+ nor [WIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719655(v=vs.85).aspx) then you have to do some parsing yourself because the format of a .ICO file is not exactly the same as a icon resource in a .EXE/.DLL so you cannot use the resource based icon functions. The official binary spec can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx) and there is a great blog series about it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101018-00/?p=12513/).

If your .ico file has more than one image in it then you must loop over the icon directories until you find a image dimension you are happy with. You can then call [`CreateIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648059(v=vs.85).aspx) to create a `HICON`.

Answer (score 3):

With `CreateIcon` you can certainly create icons but I'm not really sure you can feed it with a png-format image data.

I had success with [CreateIconFromResourceEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648061(v=vs.85).aspx) (sorry for using other language, but take it as an example, you can use that function directly in C) :

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *
CreateIconFromResourceEx = windll.user32.CreateIconFromResourceEx
```

size_x, size_y = 32, 32
    LR_DEFAULTCOLOR = 0

```
with open("my32x32.png", "rb") as f:
    png = f.read()
hicon = CreateIconFromResourceEx(png, len(png), 1, 0x30000, size_x, size_y, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR)
```

Hope it helps you.