# How to load image resource from windows `syscall` in golang?

Tags: winapi, go

I am writing a golang program using [`go-bindata`](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) to embed the image resources,  and use the `Asset(string) ([]byte, error)` function to access resources. But my existing library codes go like this:

```
func NewIconFromFile(filePath string) (uintptr, error) {
    absFilePath, err := filepath.Abs(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    hicon, _, _ := LoadImage.Call(
        0,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(absFilePath))),
        IMAGE_ICON,
        0,
        0,
        LR_DEFAULTSIZE|LR_LOADFROMFILE)
    if hicon == 0 {
        return 0, errors.New("load image failed: " + filePath)
    }
    return hicon, nil
}
```

How can I rewrite this functions to:

```
 func NewIconFromRawBytes(imgBytes []byte) (uintptr, error)
```

so it can support for loading images from `[]byte` ?  Any helps? thanks.

Edit: There is [a similar c++ version question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356001/how-to-load-a-windows-icon-using-a-pixel-buffer), how can I port it to golang.

Comment: Why are you returning a `uintptr`?

Comment: What is `LoadImage`? There seem to be a lot of assumptions in your code that aren't explained sufficiently to provide an answer.

Comment: @apxp: that's not what the warning means, and it's not useful to blindly repeat anytime you see "unsafe". The `unsafe`package is required for many things in Go, e.g. using the `sys`/`syscall` packages, and when used correctly is fully supported in future versions. That warning means it's possible to use unsafe in a way that relies on internal implementation or platform specific details, not that simply importing it makes your program non-compliant.

Comment: @Flimzy The original codes can be found at github repo: [xilp/systray](https://github.com/xilp/systray/blob/master/tray_windows.go).

Comment: @Flimzy This code strictly deals with Windows API; there are no assumptions if you know what working with it in Go is about.

Answer (score 1):

`LoadImage()` deals with Windows resources, which are built into Windows executables directly. `go-bindata` doesn't seem to deal in these, and doing this with Go directly isn't trivial.

If you want to be able to write a `NewIconFromRawBytes()` that creates an `HICON` from memory, you'll need to use the confusingly-named [`CreateIconFromResourceEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648061(v=vs.85).aspx) function. If you do that, you may want to keep [the info in the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167062/create-hicon-from-memory-on-windows) in mind.

If, however, this is an image instead of an icon and you want an `HBITMAP` out of it, you have a bit more work to do involving the [`CreateDIBSection()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183494(v=vs.85).aspx) function. [The answer here shows what to do, though understanding it may be a bit harder.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930528/how-to-convert-an-array-of-pixels-to-hbitmap) Of important note is that `CreateDIBSection()` allocates the image memory for you, so you'll have to copy it from Go to the memory location provided.

Side note: if you have a `*image.RGBA` or `*image.NRGBA`, you'll need to flip the bytes around if you want to shove that into an `HBITMAP`, as Windows expects the bytes in `BGRA` order, not `RGBA` order.